# How to reformat "gq"ed text in one line per paragraph format in Vim

Tags: vim

I have some text files previously formatted in vim using "gggqG". Now I need to convert them to one line per paragraph format. I saw a way(using :g command) to do that before, but I have forgot it. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two approaches I know of:

- Set textwidth to something big and reformat:

  ```
  :set tw=1000000
  gggqG
  ```
- Use substitute (this is more appropriate if you want to do it in a mapping):

  ```
  :%s/.\zs\n\ze./ /
  ```

Explanation of the latter:

```
:%s        " Search and replace across the whole file
/          " Delimiter
.\zs\n\ze. " Look for a character either side of a new-line (so ignore blank lines).
           " The \zs and \ze make the replacement only replace the new-line character.
/ /        " Delimiters and replace the new-line with a space.
```

Comment: the regex approach is kind of obscure. but nice. he tw=<large> approach wins on simplicity

Answer (score 3):

If your text paragraphs are separated by a blank line, this seems to work:

```
:g!/^\s*$/normal vipJ
```

`:g` global (multi-repeat)

`!/^\s*$/` match all lines except blank lines and those containing only whitespace.

`normal` enters 'normal' mode

`vip` visually select inner paragraph

`J` join lines

Comment: +1: This is very nearly perfect.

Lines with zero or more than one whitespace character may be considered empty, too. I suggest `/^\s*$/`. 

Also note that `:v` is equivalent to `:g!` 

So you can get your "vim par" down to just 17: `:v/^\s*$/norm vipJ`.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: Good catch.  There was supposed to be a `*` in there... I'll update that.  Thanks for the `:v` tip as well.

Comment: I noted that it gives the wrong output when lines are already joined. It removes an empty line. This one not: `%s/\(\S\s*\)\n\(\s*\S\)/\1 \2`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should set textwidth to very large value (like 99999999) (0 does not work for some reason) and use `gggqG`?

// I cannot tell you a way to reformat your paragraph with `:g` without knowing exactly what the paragraph is. Maybe somebody else can.