# vim: Join all lines in paragraph

Tags: vim, line

I'm trying without success to join all lines in a paragraph (block of text) using a vimscript.
I want to do this for every paragraph (block of text) and want to keep the empty lines between them.
(I don't want to use macros)

When I use the `}w` command to go to the first word in the next paragraph I noted that it does not recognize empty lines with spaces or multiple empty lines between paragraphs.
That's not what I want.

So I tried this:
do a search:
`\(^.*\S\+.*\n\)\{2,}`
do:
`normal vipgJ`
do above search again etc.

It works fine when I do it manually, but I can't put this in a script.

I tried this:

```
 function! <SID>JoinParagraphs()   
   let i = 1   
   normal gg   
   while i <= 200   
   call search("\\(^.*\\S\\+.*\\n\\)\\{2,})", "")   
   normal vipgJ   
    let i=i+1   
   endwhile   
  endfunction
```

Doesn't work...
I tried also to change the line `call search...` for
`let @/ = "\\(^.*\\S\\+.*\\n\\)\\{2,})"`
but that does a Join of all lines together (doesn't keep the empty lines).

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Even if I have found the solution in the answers below, can anyone please tell me whats wrong in above function? :)

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What behaviour do you see?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Replace all newlines followed by something other than a newline with the second matched character:

```
:%s/\(\S\)\n\(\S\)/\1 \2/
```

Another approach:

```
:%s/\n\([^\n]\)/\1/
```

Comment: @JSBangs, your code removes one empty line between the blocks of text. I would like to keep all empty line.

Comment: and it doesn't consider empty lines with one or more spaces.

Comment: @JSBangs, pattern not found (there are end of line spaces in my text).. but even if I change it to `\(.*\S.*\)\n\(.*\S.*\)` it will remove one `\n` every two lines.  What I want to obtain is to remove only `\n` when next line contains text.

Comment: @Remonn `there are end of line spaces in my text` -- that's why my regex didn't work for you... but what kind of crazy file are you working on?

Comment: @JSBangs, a text with EOL spaces, but even when I remove them, your regex can't work (see my comment above).

Comment: @Remonn, I tested this on a file with multiple empty lines between text blocks, and it doesn't remove them. Do you have "empty" lines that contain only whitespace?

Comment: Found it: This one works!! `%s/\(\s*\S\s*\)\n\(\s*\S\s*\)/\1 \2`

Answer (score 32):

Just [found this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880109/how-to-reformat-gqed-text-in-one-line-per-paragraph-format-in-vim/2882155#2882155)

```
:set tw=1000000
gggqG
```

Which is the absolute winner IMHO.

It [executes `gq`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#gq) on the motion from `gg` (start) to `G` (end of document), using a textwidth of 1000000.

Comment: nice one yes...  (I believe you forgot a line: `:%s/.\zs\n\ze./ /`)

Comment: Nope. That line is irrelevant because it was an alternative approach and won't do you what you need exactly. So, yes `gggqG` is really all there is to it (with sufficiently high `tw`)

Comment: Nice. You can select blocks of text and then use `gq` on those manually, if you don't want to join all paragraphs.

Comment: @SethDifley It [executes `gq`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#gq) on the motion from `gg` (start) to `G` (end of document), using a textwidth of 1000000.

Comment: Haha, I love this answer, creative and a little silly but effective and simple.

Answer (score 6):

Another approach that has been around since Berkeley UNIX, before vim existed... If you're on a linux/unix system, you can invoke the fmt command like so:

`:%!fmt -w 9999`

That will do it on the whole file, which might screw up stuff like numbered lists. You can do it by paragraph with:

`!}fmt -w 9999`

or do it from the command line outside of vi:

`$ fmt -w 9999 file.txt`

I like this approach because I don't have to remember to reset textwidth=80

Answer (score 6):

as was touched on in the function the easiest way is to use

**vipJ**

Visual select inner paragraph join

Answer (score 5):

#### Click: [Pragmatic approach added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651454/vim-join-all-lines-in-paragraph/5653984#5653984)

much underrated command mode and `:global`

**Update** Fixed after a correct comment. It happened with whitespace-only lines containing <kbd>Tab</kbd>-character(s)... sry bout that.

```
:g#\v[^\s\t]#normal vipJ
```

How does that work for you? (perhaps replacing `vipJ` -> `vipgJ` if you like)

**Update** Here is one that not uses normal mode (inspired by Peter's comment)

The big benefit is that it reuses the same pattern in negative and positive sense; That way it can be genericized to

```
:let @/='\v^\s*$'
:v//.,//-1 join
```

Now the second line shows the simplicity of the this approach (for every nonmatching line, join up until the next matching line). The best thing is that you can use any odd search pattern instead

Of course you could write this particular task as one line, but it wouldn't quite be as elegant:

```
:v#\v^\s*$#.,//-1 join
```

Comment: @sehe, it does a join of all lines in 1 line

Comment: @sehe, found the error. it almost works when I remove first all "end of line spaces". Only thing what still does work after it is that it removes the empty line between a single line of text and a block of text (I have 2 blocks with only 1 line of text (with an empty line above and below)).

Comment: @sehe: does work after it --> doesnt work after it (sorry I can't edit my comment anymore)

Comment: Here is an alterative that does not use normal mode: `:g/./,/\_.\_^\s*$/j`

Comment: Updated with two simpler approaches ([`gggqG`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651454/vim-join-all-lines-in-paragraph/5653984#5653984) and [`v//.,//-1j`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651454/vim-join-all-lines-in-paragraph/5651989#5651989))

Comment: yes, `:v#\v^\s*$#.,//-1 join` works very well. Have you tested JSBangs solution? (`%s/\(\s*\S\s*\)\n\(\s*\S\s*\)/\1 \2`). It works also very well.

Comment: @Remonn: I bet it works, but it made my head hurt reading it. That is not something I think I'd use next time (I'm too dumb - a.k.a. [`Don't make me think`](http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=Don't+make+me+think&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest)). Also, using builtins will give you more flexibility, and likely more efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Caveats:

The following method may remove some blank/empty lines as `J` expects a minimum of two lines.

```
:g#\v[^\s\t]#normal vipJ
```

The following method reports error if the last line is not empty as the range `.,//-1` is not valid.

```
:v#\v^\s*$#.,//-1 join
```

The best would be use `vip` to select a paragraph and use `join` to join lines. Not sure how it can be done though.

Edit:
Probably the following will do:

```
:v#\v^\s*$#exec "normal! vip:" | '<,'> join
```